# How to Upload multiple videos using ajax and jQuery. Unable Upload because of Internal server error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, video

## Unable Upload because of  Internal server error

How to Upload multiple videos using ajax and jQuery I try several times, ajax call to function not hit but  error: function   it show alert message "error" or 
"Internal server error". l try load video file less than 10MB.

---

```
if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) 
{
    var fileUpload = $("#HomeImage").get(0);
    var files = fileUpload.files;  
    var url=$('#B2BSiteUrl').val();
    // Create FormData object  
    var fileData = new FormData();

    // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object  
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
        fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);  
    }  

    $.ajax({  
        url:url,
        type: "POST",  
        contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
        processData: false, // Not to process data  
        data: fileData,  
        success: function (result) {  
            $('#Loader').hide();
            $('#btnsubmit').show();
            if (result.Message == 'This Video Already Saved') {
                alert('This Video Already Saved');
            }
        },  
        error: function (err) {  
            alert(err.statusText);  
        }  
    });  
} else {  
    alert("FormData is not supported.");  
}
```

---

Server Code

---

```
public JsonResult SaveHomePageVideo()
{
    try
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
            bool _rowsAffected = false;
            PredefinedSearchServices objPredefinedSearchServices = new PredefinedSearchServices();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];

                Logger.LogToTextFile(file.FileName);
                bool IsExist = objPredefinedSearchServices.CheckHomePageVideo(file.FileName);
                if (IsExist)
                {
                    //already exists
                }
                else
                {
                    string rootPath = Path.Combine(Common.ConfigSettings.OfflineDealImagePhysicalPath, "cms");
                    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(rootPath, "HomePageVideo")))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(rootPath, "HomePageVideo"));
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                    string fileName = file.FileName;
                    var saveFolder = Path.Combine(rootPath, "HomePageVideo");
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(saveFolder, fileName);
                    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath); //delete if exists
                    file.SaveAs(filePath); //save image

                    _rowsAffected = objPredefinedSearchServices.InsertHomeVideos(fileName);
                    _rowsAffected = true;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: `Internal server error` commonly refers to a page throwing exception in code-behind (i.e. controller code); use `catch` expression and put some breakpoints to help identify line which throwing exception.

Comment: issue is occurring in the  jQuery side. When i try to load 2 or more  videos together.